# Why is my JQuery DataTable not populating from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to create a datatable of golf players from an API call, but my table just says "No data available in table".  I have debugged through and can see that the data array contains the correct information and format, and looking at the datatables documentation, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Javascript:

```
let data;
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://pure-peak-65624.herokuapp.com/https://api.sportradar.us/golf/trial/v3/en/players/wgr/2022/rankings.json?api_key=rupvugmcybede53f3svuqqa8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log("success");
                    data = json.players;
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });

            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns:[
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'first_name'}
                ]
            });

        });
```

[Picture of empty DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evstj.png)

At first I tried to load the data into the table using ajax in the datatable function, but when that didn't work I broke it up into a separate ajax call to try and debug easier.

Comment: I know you already tried, but... It is better to use the built-in support for Ajax [provided by DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html). That will allow you to simplify your code, and avoid issues caused by asynchronous fetching of data and initialization of the DataTable. Then, if you still have an issue, show us the new code (in a new question) and clarify the structure of the JSON you are using for your data. Provide a [mre] and show a sample of the JSON as formatted text. Also include any console error messages.

Comment: I expect the earlier code (using Ajax in your DataTable) was probably missing the Ajax option `dataSrc: "players"` . See [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). Just a guess. That option tells DataTables where, in your JSON, the array is located, so it knows where to iterate, to get its row data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably fill you dataTable inside your ajax success

```js
let data;
$.ajax({
  url: "https://pure-peak-65624.herokuapp.com/https://api.sportradar.us/golf/trial/v3/en/players/wgr/2022/rankings.json?api_key=rupvugmcybede53f3svuqqa8",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    console.log("success");
    data = json.players;
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      data: data,
      columns: [{
          data: 'id'
        },
        {
          data: 'first_name'
        }
      ]


    });
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>first name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner way to do it and it fixed the issue, thank you for your help!

Comment: np, glad to help :)