# Why is my DataTable not filling in with data?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am trying to load a DataTable with data from an Ajax call.  I have successfully done this before and looking at how I've done it before I'm not sure what is not wrong.

JavaScript:

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function () {
    let data;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://pure-peak-65624.herokuapp.com/https://api.sportradar.us/golf/trial/v3/en/players/da226913-b804-48de-adbf-96e956eb75ac/profile.json?api_key=rupvugmcybede53f3svuqqa8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            console.log("success");
            data = json;
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [                            
                    { data: 'first_name' },
                    { data: 'last_name' }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });

    $("#myTable").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert($(this).text() + " was clicked");
    console.log("working");
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" class="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="stats.html">Stats</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to Statsland</h1>
    <div id="leaderboard">
        <table id="myTable" class="display compact nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example of the JSON returned by the API call:

```
{
"id": "da226913-b804-48de-adbf-96e956eb75ac",
"first_name": "Rory",
"last_name": "McIlroy",
"height": 70,
"weight": 160,
"birthday": "1989-05-04",
"country": "NORTHERN IRELAND",
"residence": "Holywood,, IRL",
"birth_place": "Holywood,, IRL",
"turned_pro": 2007,
"handedness": "R",
"abbr_name": "R.McIlroy",
"name": "McIlroy, Rory"
}
```

Using the browsers inspect tool I can see that the proper json is being returned from the API call, but I just can't figure out how to get it into the DataTable.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That JSON data you show in the question does not contain an array. Data Tables needs an array, so it can iterate over that array. Each entry in the array represents one row of table data. If that really is what your JSON looks like, then wrap it in an array: `data = [ json ];`. Also, I know I've [said this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76177394/12567365), but you can simplify your code by using DataTables' built-in support for Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the response of your ajax link (often there are errors in the request header).

Then:

```
var columns = [];

...
...

success: function (json) {
        console.log("success");
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        columns.push(
                { data: 'first_name' },
                { data: 'last_name' }
        )
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            data: data.data,
            columns: columns

        });
    },
```